# How to deserialize a string containing a list of ndb.Model entities?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2, app-engine-ndb

It's easy to pass a list of entities to a Jinja2 template. We all do something like this:

```
self.response.write(template.render({ 'entity_list': entity_list })
```

Now I want to do the reverse, and pass the list into a handler. Suppose I do it in the naive way:

```
<form action="/doit" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="entity_list" value="{{ entity_list }}">
</form>
```

My handler gets a unicode string looking something like this:

```
type(entity_list) = 'unicode'

entity_list = """
  [MyModel(key=Key('MyModel', 5321636278435840), data='first'),
   MyModel(key=Key('MyModel', 6447536185278464), data='second'),]
"""
```

What's the best way to deserialize this string into a list of MyModel entities?

I could parse the string myself, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Likewise for serializing and deserializing myself using json (with something like [ndb_json_helpers](https://gist.github.com/gregorynicholas/4724761)) or a protocol buffer.

Comment: There is no serialize/deserialize going on here.  All you did was list the entities in jinja and it use the defauilt repr/str method to list them.  What are you trying to achieve. Typically you wouldn't send the entire entity in a round trip, but just send the key (potentially dangerous) or enough bits of the key to allow you to recreate keys back on the server in a restricted fashion.

Comment: Thanks Tim! WHat you say makes perfect sense. Perhaps I am playing fast and loose with the terminology. I just see that I have enough information to reconstitute my list of entities and wonder whether there's a canonical way to go about it. I could certainly parse the string to extract a list of keys, or send just the keys to conserve bandwidth. For now I am not concerned about exposing them. In short, I am wondering whether I can profitably be lazy here and simplify my code given that I need the list in my post method.